# Can' t open .svg images

Tags: python

I'm generating QR codes with pyqrcode and I want to display them in a window. I tried:

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open("qrcode.svg")
img.show()
```

but it's not working.

Comment: Use Pillow instead, as PIL is basically dead. Pillow is a maintained fork of PIL.

Comment: PIL / Pillow does not support SVG. It does have some support for EPS (which pyqrcode can also output), if you have GhostScript installed. But why don't you use PNG? According to the pyqrcode docs you will need the pypng module to output PNG. Or you could use XBM and display the QR image in Tkinter. Another option is to install cairo, which can handle SVG. Or just view the SVG in a Web browser.

Comment: I used png in the end, but needed to know why can't I use .svg